# How do I solve $3x^2-e^x=0$?

Tags: transcendental-equations

> Solve the following equation for $x$ $$3x^2-e^x=0$$

I tried introducing the logarithm, which gives $$\ln\left(3x^2\right)=x$$ but I can't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: Note that $\ln(3x^2) =  \ln(3) + 2\ln(x)$. However this will not really help. In fact this equation cannot be solve in term of elementary functions.
See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+3x%5E2+%3D+e%5Ex)

Comment: Maple says: $\left\{  \left\{ x=-2\,{\rm W} \left({\it c1},-1/6\,\sqrt {3}\right)
 \right\} , \left\{ x=-2\,{\rm W} \left({\it c2},1/6\,\sqrt {3}\right)
 \right\}  \right\} 
$ where:$\left\{ {\it c1},{\it c2} \right\}  \in {\it integer}$ and $W$ is `LambertW` function.

Comment: I think no way to solve it analytically. I suggest solving the equation numerically.

Comment: You can solve this numerically using the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the are no elementary functions to solve this problem but we have that:

$$\text{n}x^2-e^x=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=-2\text{W}_\text{k}\left(\pm\space\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\text{n}}}\right)\tag1$$

When $\text{n}\ne0$ and $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$

Now, the real solutions are given by:

$$3x^2-e^x=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=-2\text{W}\left(\pm\space\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)\space\space\space\vee\space\space\space x=-2\text{W}_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)\tag2$$

Where $\text{W}\left(\text{z}\right)$ is [the product log function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) and $\text{W}_\text{k}\left(\text{z}\right)$ is the analytic continuation of the product log function.